# увеличить картинку при наведение js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

как увеличить эту картинку при наведении плавно? сейчас она 100 на 100 нужно чтобы становилось 130 на 130 или лучше подменять другой картинкой?

```js
var cvs=document.getElementById("canvas"); 

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); 
 function  q1187(){ 


  var im2a19=new Image(); 
im2a19.id='cmd23';
im2a19.src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/526ffd3ee4b0f4bd1c451e75/t/52e0b241e4b03bb9f732b6c6/1390457410413/House-icon-100px.png?format=100w"; 


document.body.appendChild(im2a19);

$(im2a19).on("click", function() { // функция, которая должна работать при клике, и работает 
  alert("123");


  
});


}
q1187();
```

```css
   #cmd23{
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 0px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas> <!-- полотно где отображается код -->
```

Comment: я может чего-то не понимаю, но что это за нейминг функций и переменных ?

Comment: какое то же имя нужно дать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, зачем у вас canvas в примере, но можно сделать увелечение при наведении через `css`.

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

function q1187() {


  var im2a19 = new Image();
  im2a19.id = 'cmd23';
  im2a19.classList.add("zoom-on-hover");
  im2a19.src = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/526ffd3ee4b0f4bd1c451e75/t/52e0b241e4b03bb9f732b6c6/1390457410413/House-icon-100px.png?format=100w";


  document.body.appendChild(im2a19);

  $(im2a19).on("click", function() { // функция, которая должна работать при клике, и работает 
    alert("123");



  });


}
q1187();
```

```css
#cmd23 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}

.zoom-on-hover {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.zoom-on-hover:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas>
<!-- полотно где отображается код -->
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slider-item').click(function() {//.slider-item это класс картинок которые в карусели 
  var src = $(this).prop('src');
  $('.BG_Border').html('<img src="' + src + '">');//.BG_Border в какой div выводить
}); //При клике по изображению из карусели, вывожу фотографию.
```

Только куда выводишь нужно применить стили для BG_Border img.

Comment: Только куда выводишь нужно применить стили для BG_Border img.